# Interpreting coefficients with log base 10 variables

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm having a hard time following one of the interpretation of a paper that I am reading and was wondering if anyone might be able to help me please?

The dependent variable is a dummy variable and uses a logit model. The dependent variable is either 1 if a country has fair elections and 0 if not. The explanatory variable is the log(10) of GDP.

The coefficient of the model is 0.3. So the interpretation in the paper says, the probability that a country with unfair elections transitioning to a fair election system is 0.3 higher if the country's GDP is $10,000 per year than if it is 1,000 per year.

Now the question is, can we just use the raw coefficient 0.3 and interpret as the probability?.. Don't we need to transform it?
Also, for Log(10) values, is it correct that to interpret the changes in x values as ten-folds?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the model is

```
logit(probability) ~ 0.3 x log(gdp)
```

According to this model, if the `gdp` is multiplied by ten, what is on the right is increased by 0.3 and therefore the logit of the probability is increased by 0.3. Your first question,

> can we just use the raw coefficient 0.3 and interpret as the probability?.. Don't we need to transform it?

You are right, it should be transformed. However somewhat confusingly in this case, for probabilities near 0.5, this transformed change is close to the untransformed value so it is somewhat common to forget about it.

The actual difference a logit increase corresponds to can be read from the "expit" function which is the inverse of the logit function, see https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2020/06/24/logit-and-expit/ for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By saying "the probability is increased by 0.3", you meant percentage points right? Sometimes what gives me a headache is that authors would write "increase the probability of" and I thought it implied increasing the actual percentage. And I guess sometimes it's not

Comment: "the logit of the probability is increased by 0.3" - this corresponds to a different increase in percentage points though. Yes the vocabulary is really hard to understand and will differ between authors and subfields, I have the same experience.